# Active page on top of menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a language switcher, but the active language is not in the top but its always English, how to make so that the currently chosen language is at top of the menu?

```
<div id="lang-switcher" class="ui-dropdown-list">
    <p class="ui-dropdown-list-trigger en">
        <span class="visuallyhidden">Actuall language: </span>
        <strong>ENGLISH</strong></p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="de" title="" class="en">GERMAN</a></li>
            <li><a href="lv" title="" class="en">LATVIEŠU</a></li>
            <li><a href="ru" title="" class="en">RUSSIAN</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think tou have to use as

```
<select>  
<option><a href="de" title="" class="en">GERMAN</a></option>
<option selected ><a href="lv" title="" class="en">LATVIEŠU</a></option>
<option><a href="ru" title="" class="en">RUSSIAN</a></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like its not changing the page :( It just changes the selection in the box but doesnt have any further effect

Comment: use it in <form> or also can use js